# Constructor ClipData.Item is undefined Android

Tags: java, android, image

im trying to create a item for a list, to display on a listview some pictures.
The codes is the following:

```
public static List<Item> getItemList(List<Picture> pictures, Context context)
    {
        List <Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
        for (int i = 0; i < pictures.size(); i++) {
            Item item = new Item(pictures.get(i).getID(),pictures.get(i).getAddress(),pictures.get(i).getDescription(),pictures.get(i).getPath());
            items.add(item);
        }
        return items;
    }
```

What i'm trying to do in this is to create an item for each picture on database. (getDescription would be to get the picture description from a database handler, same for address and path)

However im getting the following error in the line where i use the "gets"

The constructor ClipData.Item(int, String, String, String) is undefined.

What could this be? Thank you!

Picture Class

```
public class Picture {
int _id;
String _name;
String _address;
String _description;
String _path;

// Empty constructor
public Picture(){

}
// constructor
public Picture(int id, String name, String _address, String _description, String _path){
    this._id = id;
    this._name = name;
    this._address = _address;
    this._description = _description;
    this._path = _path;
}

// constructor
public Picture(String name, String _address, String _description){
    this._name = name;
    this._address = _address;
    this._description = _description;
    this._path = _path;
}
// getting ID
public int getID(){
    return this._id;
}

// setting id
public void setID(int id){
    this._id = id;
}

// getting name
public String getName(){
    return this._name;
}

// setting name
public void setName(String name){
    this._name = name;
}

public void setDescription(String description){
    this._description = description;
}

public String getDescription(){
    return this._description;
}

// getting phone number
public String getAddress(){
    return this._address;
}

// setting phone number
public void setAddress(String phone_number){
    this._address = phone_number;
}

public String getPath(){
    return this._path;
}

public void setPath(String path){
    this._path = path;
}
```

}

Comment: post your error logcat  and check any null value u are getting.

Comment: Can't even get to run it so i can't check logcat

Comment: you  have a Picture  entity class so u can try to use for each loop

Answer (score 0):

try to use for each loop

```
public static List<Item> getItemList(List<Picture> pictures, Context context)
    {
        List <Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
        for (Picture pic:pictures) {
            int id = pic.getID();
            String address = pic.getAddress();
            String desc= pic.getDescription();
            String path= pic.getPath();
             Item item = new Item(id ,address ,desc,path);
             items.add(item);
         }
        return items;
    }
```

Comment: Same error, says it's undefined
(The constructor ClipData.Item(int, String, String, String) is undefined.)

Comment: get line number and post Picture entity class

Comment: Picture class posted.

Comment: Nevermind, problem solved! Will post answer in 8 hours (Have 8 hours limit to answer my own questions)

Comment: what was the mistake?

Comment: @user3012563 Can you provide the answer please? I wish to take a look at that one I really need it